# Ansible add list items to list dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, arraylist, ansible

I have these data structures - several lists from which I build the list of dictionaries:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [26.167.26.11] => {
    "list_node_profile": [
        "L305-306-test1-NP",
        "L305-306-test2-NP",
        "L405-406-test1-NP",
        "L405-406-test2-NP"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [26.167.26.11] => {
    "list_node_id": [
        "305",
        "306",
        "405",
        "406"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [26.167.26.11] => {
    "list_pod_id": [
        "3",
        "3",
        "4",
        "4"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [26.167.26.11] => {
    "list_prefix": [
        "10.x.x.42/31",
        "10.x.x.41/31"
    ]
}

TASK [Create dictionary structure] ***************************************************
ok: [26.167.26.11] => (item=['L305-306-test1-NP', '305', '3'])
ok: [26.167.26.11] => (item=['L305-306-test2-NP', '306', '3'])
ok: [26.167.26.11] => (item=['L405-406-test1-NP', '405', '4'])
ok: [26.167.26.11] => (item=['L405-406-test2-NP', '406', '4'])

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [26.167.26.11] => {
    "data": [
        {
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "305",
            "node_profile": "L305-306-test1-NP",
            "pod_id": "3",
            "tenant": "common"
        },
        {
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "306",
            "node_profile": "L305-306-test2-NP",
            "pod_id": "3",
            "tenant": "common"
        },
        {
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "405",
            "node_profile": "L405-406-test1-NP",
            "pod_id": "4",
            "tenant": "common"
        },
        {
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "406",
            "node_profile": "L405-406-test2-NP",
            "pod_id": "4",
            "tenant": "common"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I would like to add prefix from the list to each dictionary from the list, so I tried this code:

```
  - name: Create dictionary structure 2
            set_fact:
              data2: "{{ data2|default([]) + [ item.1 | combine({'prefix': item.0}, recursive=True)] }}"
            with_together:
                    - "{{ list_prefix }}"
                    - "{{ data }}"
```

However it gives me this output:

```
"data2": [
        {
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "305",
            "node_profile": "L305-306-test1-NP",
            "pod_id": "3",
            "prefix": "10.x.x.42/31",
            "tenant": "common"
        },
        {
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "306",
            "node_profile": "L305-306-test2-NP",
            "pod_id": "3",
            "prefix": "10.x.x.41/31",
            "tenant": "common"
        },
        {
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "405",
            "node_profile": "L405-406-test1-NP",
            "pod_id": "4",
            "prefix": null,
            "tenant": "common"
        },
        {
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "406",
            "node_profile": "L405-406-test2-NP",
            "pod_id": "4",
            "prefix": null,
            "tenant": "common"
        }
    ]
}
```

Desired output is having prefix "10.x.x.42/31" and "10.x.x.41/31" for each dictionary from the list.

Could you please advise how to write the loop for building such structure?

Thank you!

Desired output should look like the following:

```
"data2": [
        {
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "305",
            "node_profile": "L305-306-test1-NP",
            "pod_id": "3",
            "prefix": "10.x.x.42/31",
            "tenant": "common"
        },
        {
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "306",
            "node_profile": "L305-306-test2-NP",
            "pod_id": "3",
            "prefix": "10.x.x.42/31",
            "tenant": "common"
        },
        {
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "405",
            "node_profile": "L405-406-test1-NP",
            "pod_id": "4",
            "prefix": 10.x.x.42/31,
            "tenant": "common"
        },
        {
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "406",
            "node_profile": "L405-406-test2-NP",
            "pod_id": "4",
            "prefix": 10.x.x.42/31,
            "tenant": "common"
        },
{
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "305",
            "node_profile": "L305-306-test1-NP",
            "pod_id": "3",
            "prefix": "10.x.x.41/31",
            "tenant": "common"
        },
        {
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "306",
            "node_profile": "L305-306-test2-NP",
            "pod_id": "3",
            "prefix": "10.x.x.41/31",
            "tenant": "common"
        },
        {
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "405",
            "node_profile": "L405-406-test1-NP",
            "pod_id": "4",
            "prefix": 10.x.x.41/31,
            "tenant": "common"
        },
        {
            "description": "CHG0101TEST",
            "l3out": "Shared-Test-Internet-L3Out",
            "nexthop": "10.x.x.129",
            "node_id": "406",
            "node_profile": "L405-406-test2-NP",
            "pod_id": "4",
            "prefix": 10.x.x.41/31,
            "tenant": "common"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression below does the job

```yaml
  data2: "{{ list_prefix|
             map('community.general.dict_kv', 'prefix')|
             product(data)|
             map('combine') }}"
```

The Jinja2 template below gives the same result

```yaml
  data2: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    [{% for j in list_prefix %}
    {% for i in data %}
    {{ i|combine({'prefix': j }) }},
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}]
    {% endfilter %}
```

[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    list_prefix:
      - 10.x.x.42/31
      - 10.x.x.41/31
    data:
      - {description: CHG0101TEST, node_id: '305'}
      - {description: CHG0101TEST, node_id: '306'}
      - {description: CHG0101TEST, node_id: '405'}
      - {description: CHG0101TEST, node_id: '406'}

    data2: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      [{% for j in list_prefix %}
      {% for i in data %}
      {{ i|combine({'prefix': j }) }},
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}]
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: data2|to_yaml
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  data2:
    - {description: CHG0101TEST, node_id: '305', prefix: 10.x.x.42/31}
    - {description: CHG0101TEST, node_id: '306', prefix: 10.x.x.42/31}
    - {description: CHG0101TEST, node_id: '405', prefix: 10.x.x.42/31}
    - {description: CHG0101TEST, node_id: '406', prefix: 10.x.x.42/31}
    - {description: CHG0101TEST, node_id: '305', prefix: 10.x.x.41/31}
    - {description: CHG0101TEST, node_id: '306', prefix: 10.x.x.41/31}
    - {description: CHG0101TEST, node_id: '405', prefix: 10.x.x.41/31}
    - {description: CHG0101TEST, node_id: '406', prefix: 10.x.x.41/31}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vladimir! This is very simple and working solution!